# Launch parallel independent firefox instances

Tags: firefox, session, multiple-instances, web-whatsapp

I need to open 4 Firefox "independent" sessions/instances in the same computer.

This is to the open the web-based WhatsApp GUI for 4 indepedendent business, with 4 independent phone numbers attended by the same agent. But we need them open all at the same time.

**How can I do that?**

PD: Firefox is our de-facto browser. Alternatively, if Firefox cannot do that, how can I do it in Chrome?

Comment: This is one of those tasks that is always going to be 10 times easier with 4 different browsers. You'll be fighting app signatures & prefs file locations otherwise  [unless you can compile your own & give each a different app signature]

Comment: Can you not go incognito/private on each tab?

Comment: AFAIK Multiple incognito windows share cookies/session until all incognito windows have closed. So This would allow a maximum of 2 numbers => one in the normal session, one in the incognito one. In fact, provided FF can have a "normal session" and an "incognito" one, it'd be perfect to be able to say `firefox --incognito-session=aaa` then `firefox --incognito-session=bbb` then the next and so. If this is achiavable, that works. But IDK if it's doable or not, and how.

Comment: Maybe I should try this... https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/containers - In the meantime, if anyone comes with a better idea, please share.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly

1. Open Run Box
2. Type firefox -p to open Firefox profiles
3. Create 4 profiles, like profile1, profile2, profile3, profile4
4. Go to Desktop
5. Create new shortcut
6. Put "PATH_TO_FIREFOX.exe" -p profile1
7. Give shortcut name like Profile1

Repeat process from 4. for other profiles.
[Firefox Profile Manager](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-remove-switch-firefox-profiles)

There is also another way using virtualization (sandbox) for multiple instances:

1. Install and open SandBoxie Plus
2. Right Click DefaultBox
3. Run
4. Run Program
5. Add firefox.exe Path, OK
6. Right Click firefox.exe in SandBoxie
7. Create and Save Shortcut

Repeat for other profiles.